# Initialize pointer in User on beforeSave

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to initialize/create a pointer for a User whenever they signup. However, I'm getting errors whenever I try to do this.

the error is obvious: "Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject"

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function (request, response) {

console.log("saving user" + request.object + " " + request.object.isNew());

var cardList = request.object.get("cardList");

if (cardList == null) {

    console.log("user has no cardList, creating empty: " + request.object.id);

    //Result: Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject

    request.object.set("cardList", createCardList(request.object.id));
}

response.success();
});
```

Is it possible to create other objects during a signup then add them as pointers to a user?

Can I move the code to "afterSave" and be confident that on my signup callback, the user will have this data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object `isNew()` is doesn't have an ID and you cannot set it's reference on another. It works like that because new object doesn't exist in the database yet. Use `afterSave` hook and `existed()` if you need information if object existed before this save.